# Error only on iOS 9 devices

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7, sigabrt

I can't get my app to run now on certain devices.

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppController"); <---SIGABRT
```

In the console I get...

```
-[BAPushCenter (null selector)]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a22960
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'-[BAPushCenter (null selector)]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a22960'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2502386b 0x369d6dff 0x25029035 0x369f1a4b 0x25028244 0x24f528e5 0x24f56377

0x1cfa1 0x25026b31 0x24f562b8 0x291baa29 0x293cd61d 0x293e0381 0x293ca91f

0x2d18dccd 0x2d18dfb90x24fe6827 0x24fe6417 0x24fe477f 0x24f371e9 0x24f36fdd 

0x291a143f 0x2919c18d 0x2a70d3 0x37101873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I have no idea what BAPushCenter is, I did a project search and can't find it anywhere. I used an exception breakpoint but it didn't show me any more information then original error.

Update: After testing more devices the error only seems to occur on iOS 9 devices. But iOS 9 simulator devices and any other device below iOS 9 work fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Use the breakpoint navigator to set an exception breakpoint.  It should then stop at the real error instead of that line in "main".

Comment: The breakpoint points at the same line in main

Comment: It looks the the error has nothing to do with my source code but something else. Because the app runs on all other devices I have tested so far, but not my iphone 5c with ios9

Comment: Nothing in the device console log that looks like a clue?

Comment: The only error I get in console is -[BAPushCenter (null selector)]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ea9ef0

Comment: I wonder if we're talking about the same thing.  The log I mean is what you see if you select Window->Devices in Xcode, click on your device, and look at the lines at the bottom of the window.

Comment: Same error at bottom in both device console and xcode console.

Comment: I wish I could you more info. The app shows the splash screen then crashes, so I think some hwere in my AppDelegate it causing the error possibly

Comment: One more possibility...when it crashes, try typing "bt all" (no quotes) in the debug console.  There might be something useful on one of the stacks.

Comment: Nope, no luck either

Comment: What does "no luck" mean...it didn't print anything?

Comment: When i typed "bt all" below the (lldb) line in the console it gave me another (lldb) line

Comment: What is `BAPushCenter`? If it's not your code, is it in another library you are using? Can you add the symbolicated crash log?

Comment: I did "find in project" search for BAPushCenter and nothing came up. I don't know what it is, or how to find it. And what do you mean by symbolicated crash logs? and how would I do that.

Comment: Maybe BAPushCenter is a class in your static library so that you can't find it.

Comment: What do you mean, why wouldn't I be able to find it?

Comment: N.m you were right, I couldn't search it. I figured out what library it was coming from with trial and error. thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The class was coming from one of my static libs so i wasn't able to search it.  When I figured out what lib was causing the issues I completely removed it from my app and it compiled fine. Once I get an updated version of that lib I'll put it back in my app, thanks.

Comment: What lib was it that was causing it?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, because of the "Batch Framework" my app crashes

Comment: I am having the same problem, what did you do to resolve it?